# CSS animation. From [display none; width: 0] to [display inline; width: auto]

Tags: css, animation, width

I have a hidden span inside another span. When I mouse over the outer span, I'd like to animate the hidden one to slide out and show.

```
<span class="outer">Things: <span class="number">5 <span class="details">[3 widgets, 2 spanners]</span></span></span>
```

Css:

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 1em;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.number {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.details {
    display: none;       
}

.outer:hover .details {
    display: inline;  
}
```

Here is an example of what I have working without the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/QSQBV/13/

I would like the hidden span to grow from with 0 to width 'auto' or fade in.

--EDIT--

OK, I suck at jsFiddle, I think I forgot to save it or something, anyway, the old link didn't show the effect I was after. The new updated link does show the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a `background-color` for the opacity to work properly.

Is this what you need?
JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/QSQBV/73/

Edit : Updated the JSFiddle according to your requirements. Hope this is what you need!
I used `div` instead of `span` though